# Target :after whilst using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, pseudo-element

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manipulating CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)

So i have a click event and after it has been clicked i want to target the pseudo element after.

```
    $('.expanable h3').click(function(){
        $(this).....TARGET AFTER
    });
```

I would like to change the styles of the `:after`

Comment: I think your best bet is to add/remove something from the "class", and have different CSS with and without that (and :after of course).

Comment: @boltClock i wouldn't say its a duplicate as i'm trying to target with $(this) not just in general./ pointy this is what i was going to do, but i didn't really want this approach. david i didn't know this. Thanks

Comment: I think it's a duplicate since the essence of the problem is manipulating `:after` and the rest is irrelevant noise

Comment: ye.. ok I'll agree with that :) The underlining problem is the :after rather than the this part.

Comment: If you want the next element, you could use $(this).next(). Would that help you?

Comment: although Esailija, i do feel it would help people thinking the same way as i am. On that basis it'd be educational.

Comment: @Pointy: You'll want to post that as an answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: that "duplicate" link is *fantastic*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up rules like this:

```
h3:after { content: "."; }

h3.emergency:after { content: "!"; }
```

Then adding or removing the class "emergency" will change the ending of the `<h3>` text to be either "." or "!".

There's the `attr()` mechanism in CSS that allows attributes of affected elements to serve as content, but I'm not sure that's well-supported enough to rely on.

Comment: :) i went with just adding and removing a class which had the rules set inside my styles. I just wanted a more elegant option. Cheers all the same